# How to Calculate multiple row in oracle apex 5.1?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm new in oracle apex 5.1 but I wanted calculate multiple row like as bellow:

[image]

All calculation create automatic in tabular from report:

```
row/column1.Basic Salary =($25000)
row/column2.Home rent (10% of basic)
row/column3.Medical_cost(10% of basic)
row/column4.Entertainment($800)
row/column5.Gross Amount=(all above amount)
row/column6.Daily salary(month count 30 days)=
*deduction (Minus from Gross amount)*
late free=
advance/loan=
other deduction amount=
Net Payable amount = How ?
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question but I will try to help:
I would use SQL to build the necessary calculations, it is easier than having to write javascript or plsql.
Without knowing the table structure I would do this:

```
select
  base_salary, 
  base_salary*.10 as "Home Rent",
  base_salary*.10 as "Medical_cost",
  Entertainment,
  base_salary+base_salary*.10+base_salary*.10+Entertainment as "Gross amount"
  base_salary/30* as "Daily salary"
from table_A
```

What I'm showing is that you can build the calculations on a per row basis without any programming or complex queries.

Comment: Thanks but any one help javascript or plsql coding help about calculated this table system.

Comment: @MonirKhan You never specified that in your original question.
Please review your comment, still not clear what you're asking for..